# android studio loading component with mac os x high sierra

Tags: android-studio, macos-high-sierra

My system is mac os x high sierra.
I would like to install Android Studio.
(He works perfectly on an another mac with mac os x sierra.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K0k2.png)

Impossible to load this file and so impossible to launch the application :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUm6y.png)

Comment: Who is he? :D
Anyway, the image that you shared shows that it is downloading things. Let it download (may take 30 minutes or more, depending upon your internet speed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio nativescript Mac os x10.13.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065211/android-studio-nativescript-mac-os-x10-13-2)

Comment: Hello, I am begin to understand my problem. Android Studio couldn't select my right place as : export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk but  export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<MY_USER_NAME>Android/sdk. I haven't access to this link. How could i do with prompt command ?